# Parse multi line output with regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to parse following multi line output with regex,

```
>>> a = """
... Feature 101
... Learning: Yes
... --------------
... Feature 102
... Learning: No
... """
```

What I get is only one value, shouldn't it return both the values as I have used `re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL`?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.*Feature\s*(\d+).*Learning\s*:\s*(\w+).*', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
[('102', 'No')]
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Put parentheses around the `.*` and take a look at what it matched.

Comment: Read about greedy and non-greedy qualifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the greedy `.*` (all 3 of them in the regex).
If you make them all non-greedy by appending a `?` (change them to `.*?`),
you'll get all the results you expected:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*?Feature\s*(\d+).*?Learning\s*:\s*(\w+).*?', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
[('101', 'Yes'), ('102', 'No')]
```

Also, it's always good to use raw strings with `r'...'` for regular expressions.